# How can I replace string of numbers in document.body.innerHTML with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Currently I am trying to write a function in javascript that will search through doc.body.innerHTML and search for a set string of numbers always in the same format.

Ex. 00000000123456

When it locates this number I want to have it deduct the 8 0's and replace it with only the 123456. 
Once it has only the last 6 digits I would like to make it a hyperlink to search those digits on a specific page.

If it is however any easier to code it is not entirely important to remove the 8 0's before making a hyperlink as long as I can make the hyperlink itself search the last 6 digits only.

I've tried a few different way but none work, please be easy as I am fairly new to this.

---

edit :

Example : 
page contains he following

Name : john johnson
account # : 00000000123456
email :john@johnson.com

I need to find the account number, remove the 0's from the beginning and replace the 00000000123456 with 123456. the 123456 will then become a hyperlink that will bring me to said account page.

Comment: First of all, you need a DOM walker function.

Comment: What is the need that has made you think about this solution? Just to try to search a better way to solve your problem...

Comment: I have an extension for chrome/firefox written in javascript that does roughly the same thing for various other strings i'm just having trouble doing the same thing with this since i need to delete part of the value

Comment: could you give us a part of the related `html` code?

Answer (score 0):

hope you are looking for the below:(Hint)

```
document.write("<p>Link: " + txt.link("http://www.example.com") + "</p>");
```

Comment: as i stated originally i'm very new to this so i'm unsure even how to set that up.

basically i need to search the html of the page for a string of numbers then remove x amount of numbers from the beginning and replace it as a hyperlink to a url that includes the last 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/0+(\d{6})/g, function(match, number){
    return "<a href='/search/" + number + "'>" + number + "</a>";
});
```

This finds any instance of a six-digit number preceded by one or more zeroes, and turns it into a link to '/search/[the six-digit number]'. You can run it in your browser's javascript console to test it out.

You may want to look into replacing only the relevant portion of the page, rather than the entire document (in the interest of performance).

Comment: This sound like exactly what I need!
I'll give it a shot and report back :D

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working... if it helps i already a a pagetree function to do certain actions depending on a page url. each url has its own job and title some in this instance the function is OID below that i need the script to run. is the a different way to set this up?

Comment: Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/azSM6/. The solution @louisbros posted is much safer and will teach you a bit about the DOM once you understand it. If you can get that snippet working, you should go with it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way to do it:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// search through each node in the DOM starting from the body element
(function search(child){
    for(var i = 0;i < child.childNodes.length;i++){
        search(child.childNodes[i]);
    }
    // if it's a text node
    if(child.nodeType === 3){
        // if it matches the number replace with a link
        var result =   /^(:?0{8}(\d+))/.exec(child.textContent);      
        if(result){
            link = document.createElement('a');
            // change this to be the href you want
            link.href = result[2];
            // change this to be the text you want
            link.innerHTML = 'search '+result[2];
            child.parentNode.replaceChild(link, child);
        }
    }
})(body);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/6a8fA/

Comment: thanks for the demo!
Quick questoin though, you say result 2 should be changed to what I want, seems in the demo i should change anything there because its already using the preexisting final 6 digits so i should just leave that correct?

Comment: Sorry I meant that you could format the `href` url to be how you want it but if you just want the final six digits then it's fine to leave it

Comment: yeah so if i change link to say google.com and leave the second one it will replace the 00000000123456 with search 123456 and once clicked will direct me to google.com/123456 ? thats pretty much what i need minus google being the url. I have implemented it but it doesn't seem to work. If its any consolation i do have a page tree set up to preform certain task based on a url and for the page that this info is on a have a function called oidoid so i put this under function oidoid or is there some other set up do i need to do?

Comment: try changing this `link.href = result[2];` to `link.href = 'http://www.google.com/'+result[2];` I've updated the demo so you can see what I mean.

Comment: ok. and for the createelement('a'); i leave that as a or do what?

Comment: Yes that is creating the `a` element. You only need to change the href value to be something used by your site. See demo :)

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working because i have a function labeled oidoid (doc) on my pagetree so this will only happen on a specific page as opposed to every page i load. the way it operates on jsfiddle is exactly what i want but its not actually working for me